# Request Sets, request groups, concurrent programs... what is the relationship between all these?

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence, bi-publisher

Hi Oracle XML  Publisher, I'm looking for a high-level picture of how things work. It's not clicking for some reason.

so I start out with the sample XML file, and this is my data template. And the final goal is to get a nice PDF output.

But everything in between is fuzzy to me.  What is the difference between a request set and  a request group?  Especially the administration part - what is the sinificance of the administrative roles, etc.

I found decent tutorial here ( http://oraclebisolutions.blogspot.in/2012/12/creating-reports-in-oracle-e-business.html ) , but still a bit lost.

I realize this is a bit broad, if somy apology .  I hope to answer it myself asap

Answer (score 1):

A request set is a collection of concurrent programs - for instance a request set might do a sql_load to put data into a table, then run a package to work on that data. You can schedule the request set rather than worry about the individual parts. A request group is to do with access rights - it says which concurrent programs, request sets etc you are allowed to run. You attach a request group to a responsibility.